# How to apply Thresholding in image processing

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, k-means

This is sample code for K means algorithm.

```
k = 5;
[Centroid,new_cluster]=kmeans_algorithm(inv_trans_img,k);

    for i_loop = 1:k
        cluster = zeros(size(inv_trans_img));
        pos = find(new_cluster==i_loop);
        cluster(pos) = new_cluster(pos);
       figure; imshow(cluster,[]);title('K-means');           
    end
```

I need to get the final image from this K means algorithm and I need to pass that image for thresholding process.I did it like below.

```
tumour_image=cluster;

n = 512;
binarized_img = zeros(n,n);
sort_val = sort(tumour_image(:));
    mid_val = ceil(length(sort_val)/2);
    threshold = tumour_image(mid_val);
    binarized_img(find(tumour_image>=threshold)) = 1;
    binarized_img(find(tumour_image<threshold)) = 0;
    imshow(binarized_img);title('binarized image');
```

But now the problem is,only a white image is coming as a result.How can i solve this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your threshold should be:

```
threshold = sort_val(mid_val);
```

You need to get the median of the sorted values, not the center element of `tumour_image`.

As [@NeilSlater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381797/how-to-apply-thresholding-in-image-processing/38381993#comment64173819_38381993) mentions in the comments, the reason that you're getting an all-white image from your existing code is that you are, by chance, selecting a black pixel from the original image, so when you threshold, the entire image is greater than or equal to that pixel in value.

In the case of images in which the majority of the pixels are `0`, this will still give you an all-white image as as result. One way around this, and the most analogous to what you're currently doing, is to take the median of the nonzero pixels.

```
mid_val = ceil((find(sort_val, 1)+length(sort_val))/2);
```

Alternatively, if you know which clusters you're interested in you can simply keep only those clusters.

```
binarized_image = tumour_image >= 3;   % keep clusters 3 and above
```

Comment: OP's code in the question has probably by chance picked a black pixel as the threshold

Comment: @NeilSlater Exactly. I should probably add that in, thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply,but still,I'm getting the same result as before.

Comment: @temp Can you add a sample of `tumour_image` to your question?

Comment: It's possible that the majority of your image is black, which would cause the corrected code to still fail.

Comment: Okey. Is it a good idea to get white pixels instead of black pixels,how can i do it?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to threshold. One idea would be to take the median of the nonzero elements of the image. Or, since you've got 5 clusters, you could take only the pixels in clusters `3, 4, and 5`. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, it's impossible for me to say which way would be better.

Comment: I need to find the area of tumor,so I'm applying thresholding process to the extracted cluster.But I'm stuck with this threshloding now.please suggest me an idea.

Comment: Haha, I kinda gathered that. :) I don't know what your image looks like or what the area of the tumor is, or which clusters correspond to the tumor. So without more information I'm a bit stuck as well. I've added code for the two options I gave earlier, but I can't say which will give you the results you want.